# Stop List CursorAdapter for updating

Tags: android

I've a ListView that uses Cursor adapter and it seems that the list automatically updates when there is new data in db. Occassionally I would want to stop that from happening.

ps notifyDataSetChanged is not called specifically from anywhere
Can someone tellme why is it still being updated?

Comment: Take a look at the [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292182/how-to-suspend-notification-to-observers-while-doing-many-changes-using-a-content)

Comment: Can you post the relevant code from your project?